# Android TextView dynamically re-centering

Tags: android, textview

I have a `TextView` that I want centered in my layout, so I have the following:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/workoutText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="This is dynamic"/>
```

My problem is that I don't want the centering placement to be re-evaluated every time the text changes. When the text changes to "This is longer dynamic text", the center of the text will be re-evaluated thus pushing the text over to the left on the screen. I only want the center to be evaluated based on my initial static text I put in the layout. Is there a way to do this?

I have succeeded in accomplishing my end goal by placing another `TextView` below with:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/workoutText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0px"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="This is longer dynamic text"
    android:alpha="0"/>
```

But this feels a bit hacky and would fail to work if the text dynamically changed to something longer than "This is longer dynamic text".

Comment: It sounds to me like you actually want a left margin or padding instead of centering the text.

Comment: If i understand , you would your text in the centre of TextView??

Comment: Well actually I want my text left-aligned inside TextView, but I want the TextView centered in parent.

Comment: @AdamJohns can you post your full xml?

Comment: @Karakuri the problem with that is that I want the text to be _basically_ in the center of the screen always. If I do a left margin from the left edge of parent view, that horizontal centering could differ greatly from device to device.

Answer (score 0):

you should add a gravity proprety to the TextView like this

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/workoutText"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
android:gravity="center"
android:text="This is dynamic"/>
```